# Java 8 idiomatic way to apply a Lambda to a List returning another List?

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, list-comprehension

What's the most idiomatic mechanism to apply a lambda to every item in a list, returning a list made up of the results?

For example:

```
List<Integer> listA = ... imagine some initialization code here ...

List<Integer> listB = listA.apply(a -> a * a);   // pseudo-code (there is no "apply")

/* listB now contains the square of every value in listA */
```

I checked the API javadocs and also looked into Apache Commons, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add to @Eran's answer I have a helper method:

```
public static <T, R> List<R> apply(Collection<T> coll, Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {
    return coll.stream().map(mapper).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

can be used as:

```
List<Integer> listB = apply(listA, a -> a * a);
```

(Note: will require Java 1.8 or higher.)

Comment: This would fit nicely as a default method on collections.

Comment: This is terribly inefficient if you ever want to apply more than a single mapping operation.

Comment: @CodeConfident you could use `andThen` to combine multiple functions before passing them to this method.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Agreed, and I agree that you've provided what the question asked. I just wanted to highlight this to clients of your API.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I think it's also lucky that this is Java, not say Kotlin, since the `apply(list, fn)` syntax does not readily favour nesting `apply(apply(apply(list, f1), f2), f3);`. In Kotlin you would likely provide a `list.apply(fn)` syntax, which would be more likely to provoke inefficient call chaining `list.apply(f1).apply(f2).apply(f3);`

Answer (score 28):

You can use a `Stream` with `map` and `collect` :

```
listB = listA.stream()
             .map (a -> a*a)
             .collect (Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

The most standard way is to just [collect them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) at the end:

```
List<Integer> listA = ... imagine some initialization code here ...
List<String> listB = listA.stream()
                         .map(a -> a.toString())
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note how the map function introduces a transform from, in this case, Integer to a String, and the list returned is of the `List<String>` type. The transform is performed by the map, and the List is generated by the collector.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to use a third party library, you may use powerful new collections.

```
// import javaslang.collection.*;
listB = listA.map(f);
```

These Java 8 collections are immutable and can be compared to those of Scala and Clojure. Please read more [here](http://blog.javaslang.io/functional-data-structures-in-java-8-with-javaslang/).

Btw - there is also syntactic sugar for for-loops:

```
// import static javaslang.API.*;
// import javaslang.collection.Stream;
Stream<R> result = For(iterable1, ..., iterableN).yield((e1, ..., eN) -> ...);
```

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Javaslang.